# wget page-requisites in a different folder?

Tags: download, resources, directory, wget

I'm using wget to download an HTML page with all its requisites. I would like to know if is it possible to download the page requisites (css, images, scripts, etc) in a different folder than the html page.

For example, right now if the html page has a link like the following one:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The result from wget folder structure looks like:

```
├── index.html
├── css
    ├── style.css
```

Is there any option to change the style's output folder name? Like so:

```
├── index.html
├── **another name**
        ├── style.css
```

Thank you so much!